# How to insert json array to mysql database usnig Node JS and Express

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json, express

I'm creating a MySQL database and I want to insert about 1000 records that are structured in a JSON array

**This is the JSON array that I'm importing:**

```
 [
  {
   "DESCRIPTION": "انفرتر 1   حصان أحادي",
   "TYPE": "ODE-2-12075-1K012XX",
   "CLASSIFICATION": "VFD",
   "BRAND": "INVERTEK",
   "ORIGIN": "UK",
   "FAMILY": "ODE-2",
   "ar_classification": "انفرتر"
  },
 {
  "DESCRIPTION": "انفرتر 2   حصان أحادي",
  "TYPE": "ODE-2-120150-1K012XX",
  "CLASSIFICATION": "VFD",
  "BRAND": "INVERTEK",
  "ORIGIN": "UK",
  "FAMILY": "ODE-2",
  "ar_classification": "انفرتر"
 },
 {
  "DESCRIPTION": "انفرتر كتيم 3 حصان أحادي بدون\nمقاومة ومفتاح",
  "TYPE": "ODE-2-24400-3K04N-XX",
  "CLASSIFICATION": "VFD IP55",
  "BRAND": "INVERTEK",
  "ORIGIN": "UK",
  "FAMILY": "ODE-2",
  "ar_classification": "انفرتر"
 }
]
```

```js
  const {readFileSync} = require('fs')
  //Here is where the Json array is located
  const first = readFileSync('./Zahabi-Products.json', 'utf8')
 const products = JSON.parse(first)

   
    pool.query("INSERT INTO products SET ?", products, 
        function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('data inserted');
     });
```

But the result is that only the first object in the array is being inserted

How could I insert all of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried this and it worked, but I think that is not the perfect answer***

```
var test02 = {}
for(var i = 0; i <= products.length; i++ ){
   test02 = products[i]
   pool.query("INSERT INTO products SET ?",test02 , 
   function(err, result) {
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('data inserted');
});
```

}